# Is 12 Android emulator safe for PC?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation, virtualization

In `Android Studio` (version: Android Studio Dolphin 2021.3.1 Patch 1) before downloading virtual image with Android 12 (API 33, `Tiramisu`) I had to agree to the license agreement that start with the following worrying me statement:

> To get started with the Android SDK Preview, you must agree to the
> following terms and conditions. As described below, please note that
> this is a preview version of the Android SDK, subject to change, that
> you use at your own risk. **The Android SDK Preview is not a stable**
> **release, and may contain errors and defects that can result in serious**
> **damage to your computer systems, devices and data**.

The same for 32 API (Android 11). For Android 7 there was no such warning.
Is it safe now to install and use this emulators? What damage can happen to computer? How to prevent it? Does someone already install and use them?

In the [similar question](https://www.reddit.com/r/PCSX2/comments/g7s71f/can_running_the_emulator_damage_your_laptop/) I found the following recommendations about potential overheating PC:

> It could potentially damage your laptop if it overheats. But that is
> why the fan is running. It is trying to cool down. If it gets too hot
> your computer will start throttling programs, apps and processes to
> try and cool down. And if it gets too hot it should shut itself down
> to prevent damage. Make sure to keep and vents and fans clear, clean
> and free for airflow.

This is the only main problem with this emulators?

Answer (score 1):

Any emulator is doing something the pc isn't handled to do, this goes double for mobile apps. Worst case scenario I had with emulating a G phone was that when closing the app the pc would slowly start to crash which I would need to restart in order to get it working normally (also the lack of space on the ssd made a problem too) but no major damage was made. Of course don't neglect your pc, the more you complex stuff you try to emulate the more your pc will gasp for air, give it some breathing room now and then, take a break and keep going. If for example you are using flutter dart has a nice API that you can use online that won't effect your pc at all.

Also this goes triple for laptops since most don't have that good of a cooling.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install 33 API (`Tiramisu`) emulator on Notebook ThinkPad T420 (processor: i5-2520M CPU 2.50GHz, memory: 8 Gb, SSD) with enabled virtualization. Emulator boots about 8 minutes. Works terribly slow. Always reads or writes something to SSD (since memory is not enough it is using swap). Not possible to use. Temperature of CPU is near to critical level: ~90°C.
PC must have more resources otherwise there is real risk to damage it.